# pyspark converting unix time to date

Tags: pyspark, unix-timestamp

I am using the following code to convert a column of unix time values into dates in pyspark:

```
transactions3=transactions2.withColumn('date', transactions2['time'].cast('date'))
```

The column transactions2['time'] contains the unix time values. However the column date which I create here has no values in it (date = None for all rows). Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from_unixtime`. `expr("from_unixtime(timeval)")`